# Учитывается ли протокол http или https при cors?

Tags: nginx, cors

В конфиге сервера учитываются только доменные имена как разрешенные, или же протокол тоже учитывается? К конфигу сервера доступ не имею, пытаюсь отправить post запрос с http//домен1.домен.ру на https//апи.домен.ру. Запрос уходит, но заголовки не проставляются и в ответе вместо post появляется options.

Comment: options и https никак не связаны, options отправляется перед любым post-запросом именно для проверки cors

Comment: А учитывает ли сервер https или нет - это от самого сервера зависит, про который вы никакой информации не дали

Comment: А preflight 429 что означает?

Comment: @andreymal вопрос заключается в том, что при добавлении доменов как разрешенные учитывается протокол или нет. Вопрос общий а не про тот сервер о котором у меня нет информации

Comment: cors - это в первую очередь браузерная фича: сервер чаще всего просто отправляет или не отправляет разрешающие заголовки, в том числе список разрешённых origin, а браузер перед передачей ответа скрипту проверяет, что с заголовками всё в порядке. Отправляет ли сервер заголовки или нет - зависит от того, как он настроен, а вы про него ничего рассказывать не хотите :) А браузер https игнорирует (лишь запрещает http-запросы на https-страницах, но cors тут ни при чём)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, источники HTTP и HTTPS различаются.

Происхождение - это комбинация имени хоста, порта и схемы.

`http://foo.example.com:8080/
  ^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^
   ||           ||        ||
 scheme      hostname    port`

Если не все эти поля совпадают между двумя ресурсами, тогда ресурсы имеют разное происхождение. Таким образом, вы должны прямо указать, доступен ли ресурс из источника с помощью схемы HTTP или источника с помощью схемы HTTPS.

В некоторых браузерах заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin содержит только один источник (или *), отправленный с каждым ответом; однако ваш сервер может обнаружить заголовок запроса Origin и отправить его в исходный код ответа CORS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19542686

Comment: Бездумный копипаст гуглоперевода с qaru.site, ай-ай-ай. Определились бы с переводом термина origin для приличия хотя бы

Comment: Да ладно, ответ понятен более чем

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы сервер позволил CORS, он должен отправить в ответе HTTP-заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, в котором будут перечислены разрешённые origin'ы. Origin - это `scheme://host`; их может быть несколько через запятую. Что и как перечислит сервер, зависит исключительно от него самого, поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос зависит от конкретного сервера и его конкретных настроек, а вы не хотите сознаваться почему-то.

Я пытался прочитать какой-нибудь стандарт по CORS, но однозначного ответа, учитывается ли `scheme` при сравнении origin'ов, не нашёл (хотя может у меня просто плохо с английским). Ну да ладно: давайте просто возьмём тестовый сервер, возьмём самый популярный браузер Chrome и попробуем поотправлять запросы с CORS и поотвечать на него разными заголовками!

Отправлять будет с условного `example.com` на условный `example.org` примерно такой запрос в JS-консоли хрома:

```
fetch('https://example.org/cgi-bin/test.py', {'method': 'POST'});
```

Во всех случаях сервер будет отвечать HTTP 200, но с разным HTTP-заголовком `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. В случае проблем в консоль вывалится ошибка, несмотря на то, что результата от промиса мы не получаем.

---

**Эксперимент 1: `http` → `https`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`**

Работает.

**Эксперимент 2: `http` → `https`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`**

Не работает:

> Failed to load `https://example.org/cgi-bin/test.py`: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Отсюда уже можно сделать вывод, что протокол имеет значение. Но едем дальше.

**Эксперимент 3: `https` → `https`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`**

Не работает с аналогичной ошибкой.

**Эксперимент 4: `https` → `https`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com`**

Работает.

---

Итого: протокол учитывается браузером при проверке CORS, а что с ним делает сервер — зависит от конкретного сервера. Возможно, он захочет прописать «правильный» протокол в заголовке, а возможно не захочет.

Comment: Да у меня у самого нет инфы о сервере. Спасибо за ответ!